# Heroku Maven github deploy

Tags: heroku

I have some issue in heroku deploy

```
2020-05-29T00:59:40.015516+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/barbershop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2020-05-29T00:59:40.082046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-05-29T00:59:40.135944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-29T00:59:44.102979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=powerful-taiga-48681.herokuapp.com request_id=759de18f-db81-47ca-8108-452945494b3d fwd="179.180.253.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Unable to access jarfile target/barbershop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Did you check if `target/barbershop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is in your file system?

Comment: Is not in my files, I viewed this later, but when heroku goes up the project it doesn't compile and generate this file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm deploying by github, but when the deploy is finished is not generating my jar file, so I needed to create an sh file to menage that for me, like this:

start.sh

```
./mvnw clean package
./mvnw build
./mvnw package
java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/barbershop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Procfile

```
web: chmod a+x ./mvnw; chmod a+x ./start.sh; ./start.sh
```